# Sublime Text 2 packages ignored

Tags: sublimetext2, package-control

So after switching over to Sublime Text last year, it has become my editor of choice, and I have installed several different packages via the excellent Package Control and basically customized it all to my liking. After a couple months of infrequent use, I jumped back into a code-intensive project and fired up ST2 only to find that none of my packages are working.

After some digging, it finally occurred to me to open my preferences file, only to find all of my installed packages in the "ignored_packages" list. WTF?

Has anyone else experienced this or know what would have caused this? I do some funny things in my sleep sometimes, but not this!

Comment: Have you been playing with the Sublime Text 3 beta? Are you on a Mac or Linux or Windows?

Comment: mac os 10.8.4. I did download ST3 although didnt do much with it, b/c my ver 2 is so customized its like a comfortable pair of shoes... my understanding was that the different versions kept completely separate files and shouldn't interfere with each other?

Comment: yes, the versions are different, but if you were mucking around with other people's scripts to move from ST2 to ST3, someone could have written something that moves everything to ignored_packages as there's a new format for ST3 packages. That's pretty much all I can think of. Weird issue...

Comment: does anyone else have access to your computer? Sounds like it could be a prank, as I haven't encountered any packages that do this, and I've tested quite a few. If no one has access to your box, you could try setting up a fresh install of ST2, then reinstall your packages one by one and see if anything changes. Sorry I don't have anything more brilliant than that...

Comment: This happened to me today. I removed all the packages that I actually wanted from `ignored_packages` in Preferences.sublime-settings, it's all better.  Whew!

Comment: This happened to me again today. No visible signs of an auto-update having run or anything out of the ordinary, and I have been using ST2 daily. But sure enough, I opened it up this morning and all of the packages I have installed are in `ignored_packages` again. Happily this time I know how to fix quickly, but I'm still stumped and submitting it as an issue.

Comment: This happened to me again today. I started up ST2, with the console open, and as the typical start-up update ran, some packages were added to `ignored_packages`. Something then hit a snag, and I had to force quit the application and start again, with no issues. I started ST3, watched packages get added to `ignored_packages` (though not as many), but then get removed again, so it may be an issue with the different versions, or it may be coincidence.

Comment: Will Bond, the Package Control author, just emailed me and said he couldn't reproduce it. Could you guys post a list of what packages got moved? Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My earlier [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177107/sublime-text-2-packages-ignored#comment26633076_18177107) notwithstanding, I think I've figured out what's going on. The issue seems to be Package Control, most likely the new version update to 2.0. I just restarted ST2 after having it open for the past few days, and happened to have the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) open, and saw that several of my packages, including Tag, Terminal, and SublimeREPL, were added to the ignored packages list. This typically happens when a package is being updated or removed, and is done so it can't be used halfway through the operation before everything is synced. At any rate, for me there was some sort of error, and I had to force quit Sublime and restart it. I immediately checked my preferences, and sure enough several packages were in the `"ignored_packages"` array.

So, I'm guessing something like this happened to you, and for whatever reason the packages weren't removed from the ignored list, possibly because the system update didn't complete normally. Hopefully this won't happen again, but if it does you'll know where to look. Additionally, if it does happen again, I'd submit an [issue](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues) on Github, as this may be a bug.

---

### ***Update***

My [issue](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/564) on Github has been merged into [this one](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/558), and if you scroll all the way down to the bottom wbond has [a fix for now](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/558#issuecomment-22680296): Download [`Package Control 2.0.1-beta`](https://sublime.wbond.net/prerelease/Package%20Control.sublime-package), put it in your `Installed Packages` folder (removing the one that's already there), and adding the repository `https://sublime.wbond.net/prerelease/packages.json` by selecting `Preferences -> Package Control -> Add Repository`. Restart ST2, and see what happens, especially after restarting multiple times. If you still have bugs or odd behavior, please [add to the issue](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/558).

Comment: Yes! I've been having a sneaking suspicion that it had something to do with the upgrade to Package Control, as I think I first noticed it after that. Unlikely that someone was messing with my setup, although thats a perfect nerdy prank... now who can i pull it on......

Comment: It happened to me as well, and even after removing everything from ignored_packages yesterday, after firing up Sublime 2 today, everything is in there again. Annoying enough.

Comment: Sorry, Matt if that was bad etiquette on my part.. I'm new to Stack Overflow, but i unaccepted it because the problem persisted, and to me it is still an unanswered question. I'll re-tick it, as I think it is on the right track....

Comment: well, the problem is definitely with Package Control, and the package upgrade process. See [this issue](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues/564) on github. The problem will potentially persist intil Will Bond (the author of Package Control) figures it out.

Comment: Not sure how, but my tiny collection of four packages were all ignored under ST2. Sometimes I forget to close Sublime and Ctrl-C kill it from the console where I started it. Emptying the ignored_packages list fixed it. If anyone else is wondering where to find `ignored_packages`:  it's a hard-coded array in the `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file (to open in Sublime, choose Preferences > Settings - User).  Just remove everything inside the array's [square brackets].

Comment: @MarkBerry thanks for the clarification, but I'd add one more detail - make sure to leave `Vintage` in the `"ignored_packages"` array, otherwise Sublime will enter vim mode, which is rather difficult to use if you're not familiar with vi/vim.

Answer (score 5):

I am adding this even if it's an old thread because the answer did not solved my problem, but it pointed me in the right direction.

Since it was a problem due to Package Control trying to update packages and I didn't want to mess with repos and stuff, first I tried to upgrade the packages "manually" using Package Control and I noticed that there was a 1-to-1 match between the items in the `ignored_packages` array and the packages that needed to be upgraded.

After updating, just remove the packages from the array and restart ST2: no more weird ignored packages in the array.