# Sublime Text Soda Theme Black Sidebar Issue

Tags: sublimetext2

I've done some searching and not been able to find a solution to my problem. I installed the Sublime Text soda light theme to Sublime a while back but when I go and open it today it looks like this:

[image]

In the image, the text is from my Sublime preferences. Just wondering if someone's come across this issue and knows how to solve it. I've tried installing the theme again, restarting Sublime, but nothing's worked so far.

Comment: So what is the problem / question?

Comment: @AGS - the sidebar, tab bar at the top, and bottom bar are all completely blacked out. See my answer below for the explanation and fix.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with a [minor upgrade to Soda](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/issues/177) and a quirk with Package Control. Package Control upgrades all eligible packages when you first start Sublime, after a certain amount of time has passed since the last upgrade attempt. While these packages are waiting to be upgraded, Package Control adds them to the `"ignored_packages"` array in your preferences. Due to [an issue with Package Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18178163/1426065), even though the package gets upgraded, it doesn't always get removed from `"ignored_packages"`. You just happened to post an image of your user preferences, and right there it shows `"Theme - Soda"` as being ignored. Just remove it from there (including the trailing comma `,` after `Vintage`), save, restart Sublime, and you should be all set. This fix works for both Sublime Text 2 and ST3. If you're using ST3, however, please make sure to upgrade to the latest build - 3062 currently - as (from [the README](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme#installation)) Soda is designed to work with the latest dev builds. There were some changes to the sidebar in 3062 that Soda's author took advantage of, so there may be some issues with earlier versions.